# What does Vuetify `new Vue({ vuetify, render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')` do? Can I ignore it?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs, vuetify-loader

I'm building a component library based on Vuetify.

Vuetify installation tells people to add this line

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

However, I want people to be able to just import my component.

It looks like this

```html
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
import { HelloWorld } from "MyComponentLibrary";

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

Now, if this line of Vuetify is necessary...

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify,
});
```

I will have to make my component library API looks like this

```js
import { reExportedVuetify } from "MyComponentLibrary";

new Vue({
  vuetify: reExportedVuetify,
});
```

So, what does `new Vue({ vuetify })` do?

Comment: That line actually instantiates and launches your Vue app. You would not put that in an importable component.

Comment: `Vuetify` line initializes Vuetify library and registers its components inside your app. I think that it will be best if you do not build/bundle your library but provide it as ES6-importable group of components.